# trying to move the uploaded file but its not working

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to moving the upload file but its not working Please tell me what's wrong?
`move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
"upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
 echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];`

Here are the two warnings

`Warning: move_uploaded_file(upload/DSCN87279.JPG): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\prcticsephp\upload2.php on line 26`

Here is the second warning

`Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpA1AD.tmp' to 'upload/DSCN87279.JPG' in C:\xampp\htdocs\prcticsephp\upload2.php on line 26
 Stored in: upload/DSCN87279.JPG`

The browser showing me these two warnings and this code also does not move file to uplod folder

Comment: does the directory exist bcoz the first error is for that

Comment: __Don’t__ use `$_FILES["file"]["name"]` as name for the file without any checks. _Research_ what the security implications of this are, if you are not aware of it.

Comment: Tell us what the _full_ path to the directory in your file system is then.

Comment: `C:\xampp\uplod` it is the full path of my directory

Comment: in that directory i want to move my uploaded file

Comment: So the directory you have specified in your script does _not_ exist. You need to update your knowledge on how relative paths work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$image_name= $_FILES['image']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($file,"photos/".time().$image_name); //use time to make sure that the image name is not repeated also the photos is a directory located in the root directory
```

Comment: `addslashes` is nonsense in this context.

Comment: @CBroe i just copied and pasted the code from my upload script here

Comment: @CBroe the `addslashes` is part of an array of security checks just to be safe

Comment: On a windows file system it would have a negative effect, because the backslash is the directory separator there.

Comment: This is not a “security check”, it is just _mindless_ use of a function without thinking what the _right_ action to take would be.

Comment: @CBroe Like i said it part of an **ARRAY** of security checks

Comment: You code as posted here does not show any “array of security checks”. The way it is used here is just __wrong__.

Comment: @CBroe thats because its just the answer to the question no need for me to show my arrays of security checks

Comment: You are showing code here that is _wrong_ and potentially _harmful_ … so expect a downvote of your answer.